# Electron windows installer too slow

Tags: windows, installation, electron

Im using electron windows installer: https://github.com/electron/windows-installer and when running on windows the installer, it takes really long (more than 10 minutes), is this normal?

Comment: If you are installing lot of small files, it can really slow down the process. Also check your disk - if you have W10 and slow HDD it's usual that it can take lot of time, another thing is windows defender - it can double the time of file copy.

Answer (score 0):

@danibuiza I have found that electron applications that include native modules (ones which require that you compile them with `electron-rebuild`.rebuild) take exceedingly long amounts of time to install, as compared with other apps. This has less to do with the installer and more to do with the packaging of application. Since you can't package native modules into the electron blob `app.asar`  (you must list your native packages in the `unpackDir` option of the `asar` configuration when doing the electron-packager), this means the entire tree structure of such packages must be used and installed as a collection of files. This is often a large additional number of files in the electron application, as opposed to them all being compressed into the asar along with all other application components.

In any case, its important to have your `electron-packager` option settings be as optimized as possible so that your installer will later have the most concise collection of assets as possible. In my opinion, this means properly using the `asar` and `prune` options when using `electron-packager`.

Hopefully those suggestions will help with your resultant overall install time.